# How to Compare two sets namely set A and set B while both contains set of ids then I need to remove id from second set

Tags: apex, set, collection

Is it possible to Compare two sets namely set A and set B while both contains set of ids.

I need to check if set A contains ids which is present in set B.

**If it is present then i need to remove from set B.**

Example:

```
set<id> SetA= new set<id>{'00524000001IFbNAAW','00524000001IFbVAAW','00524000001IFrHAAW','00524000001IFxDAAW','00524000001IFrEAAW','00524000001IFrGAAW'};

set<id> setB= new set<id>{'00524000001IFbNAAW','00524000001IFbVAAW','00524000001IFrHAAW','00524000001IFxDAAW','00524000001IFrEAAW','00524000001IFrGAAW','00524000001IFmPAAW','00524000001IFnKAAW','00524000001IFgPAAW'};
```

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this way

```
Set<Id> setAIds = new set<Id>{'0039000001pJpRH', '0069000000K8YjG'};
Set<Id> setBIds = new set<Id>{'0039000001pJpRH'};

system.debug('====setAIds==='+setAIds);
system.debug('====setBIds==='+setBIds);

for(Id objId: setAIds){
    if(setBIds.contains(objId))
        setBIds.remove(objId);
}
system.debug('====setAIds==='+setAIds);
system.debug('====setBIds==='+setBIds);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use "containsAll" and "removeAll" method of set. 
list:

```
Boolean containsAll = satb.containsAll(setA);
```

This "ContainsAll" method will store true if all the elements are present in setB.

Check this article

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm